# hide / show content based on MULTIPLE URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Wondering if there is a possibility at hiding or showing content based on MULTIPLE URLS?

Eg. User is at home or index with www.url.com/ or www.url.com/index.html

Specific element `display: block` or `display: none`

```
  if(location=="http://domain.com/") {
```

Works great, but how could I specify multiple URLs in the same above similar format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(location=="http://google.com") {
     //Do something here   
} else {
     //Do something else here   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I got downvoted, just never had this problem to try this technique. Thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sammy.js** (http://sammyjs.org/). It has a nice URL routing feature.

Answer (score 0):

By testing `location.pathname` like this :

```
document.getElementById('specific').style.display = location.pathname === "/index.html" ? 'none' : 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to `$_GET` URL information. Let's say you have the following URL:

```
https://www.wherever.com/some_file.php?css1=1&css2=1
```

At another time, let's say the URL looks like:

```
https://www.wherever.com/some_file.php?css3=1&css4=1
```

When you're writing your PHP page that generates HTML:

```
<?php
$css = '';
function link_builder(){
  $a = func_get_args(); $lo = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"; $lc = "' />"; $o = '';
  foreach($a as $v){
    $o .= "$lo$v$lc";
  }
  return $o;
}
if(isset($_GET['css1'], $_GET['css2']) && $_GET['css1'] === '1' && $_GET['css2'] === '1'){
  $css = link_builder('cssPath1.css', 'cssPath2.css');
}
if(isset($_GET['css3'], $_GET['css4']) && $_GET['css3'] === '1' && $_GET['css4'] === '1'){
  $css = link_builder('cssPath3.css', 'cssPath4.css');
}
echo $css;
?>
```

With this methodology you can create separate external CSS files in advance, which can be cached into the Client's Browser memory. JavaScript styling won't do that.